# Failed to create new user in Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn

How can I create new account in my vps? I want to create a VPN service. If I type `adduser` in putty it works I can use my created account in VPN app but that account is able to login into my VPs as root using the given username and pass but I don't like that.

I already tried this code but it doesn't work

```
usermod -s /sbin/nologin username
```

What happen when I use that code is

1. I created a new user
2. It works on VPN app
3. It works to login as root
4. When I type `usermod -s /sbin/nologin`, cannot login as root and in VPN app

I want is

1. I use `adduser`
2. The user can use that account in VPN app
3. But that username cannot be used to login in my vps as root

This code

```
usermod -s /sbin/nologin username
```

works on my debian vps but not working on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following link could help resolve your question. [How to Add and Delete Users on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. External links die, making such answers useless. Please [edit] your post to include essential parts of the linked website and then link back to it.